# mod_rewrite and anchor issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, anchor

My  htaccess looks like this in order to create SEO urls:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

#marker share
RewriteRule ^share/(.*).html index.php?share=1&introsplash=0&markerid=$1 [L]

#marker share with map only.
RewriteRule ^map/(.*)/share/(.*) index.php?mapid=$1&markerid=$2&share=1&introsplash=0 [L]

#map only
RewriteRule ^map/(.*) index.php?mapid=$1 [L]
```

the problem is now if I create a link to an anchor like

```
<a href="#myanchor">go to my anchor</a>
```

the page reloads to this url: http://mydomain.com/app/#myanchor
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem appears to be that your rules are being applied one after another on same URL.

Put an additional condition in your rule to avoid rule being repeated:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

#marker share
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^share/(.*)\.html$ index.php?share=1&introsplash=0&markerid=$1 [L,QSA]

#marker share with map only.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^map/(.*)/share/(.*)$ index.php?mapid=$1&markerid=$2&share=1&introsplash=0 [QSA,L]

#map only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^map/(.*)$ index.php?mapid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Take note of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which avoids very next `RewriteRule` if request is for a valid file.

Comment: This didn't work.. 

My SEO URL: http://www.example.com/app/share/test-user-180222.html
My real URL: http://www.example.com/app/index.php?share=1&markerid=test-user-180222

when click on link to anchor it points to: http://www.example.com/app/#myanchor

Comment: Anchors don't reach web server at all, those are only for the browser.   See what happens when you manually enter `http://example.com/app/share/test-user-180222.html` in the browser.

Comment: after your tip "Anchors don't reach web server at all" I checked my html an I had <base href="/app/" /> in place... Removed it and it now works!

Thanks.